# I want to retrieve image from my table (index_img) into my jsp page

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, jsp

```
  **How can I retrieve jpg image from my sql database..?
  I want to retrieve image inside the image tag.
  **


   Index.jsp  

      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
         <head>
         </head>
          <body >
       <%          
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                  Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portfolio","root","root");
                   Statement st3= con.createStatement();
                  ResultSet rs3=st3.executeQuery("select * from index_img");
   %>          


            <section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row no-gutter popup-gallery">

                      <%  
              while(rs3.next())  
                    {  %>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/portfolio/thumbnails/wildlife/wl1.jpg" class="portfolio-box">




         <img src=" #" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                       <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                            <%=rs3.getString(2) %>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="project-name">
                                           <%=rs3.getString(3) %>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                       </div>

                         <%}%>

                    </div>
                    </div>   

            </section>
</body>

        </html>
```

**I'm using this table to store the image in the sql database :
  The table is storing id , category and description about the image. And also 
 storing the image location.
   I already retrieve the category and description column ...But I don't know how to retrieve jpg image from the column image **

```
        Index_img table

            Create Table index_img 
            ( 
               id int primary key,
               category  varchar(100) ,
               description  varchar(500) ,``
               image  blob
            ) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and update your question then.

Comment: I am using stackOverflow first time , don't know how to operate it....if someone can give solution to my problem here , it will be very nice of him\her...@JozefChocholacek

Comment: what is the type of your image? JPG/BMP/GIF/etc?

Comment: jpg image....@Rudy

Comment: @YogeshSati _I am using stackOverflow first time , don't know how to operate it_ - that's exactly why I pointed you to these two pages. There you can learn, how to "operate" StackOverflow. If you **ask good question**, you have much higher chance to **get a good answer**. If people have first to "decrypt" what you are actually asking, there is a big chance they just skip it.